# URLSearchParams in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i want to send a fetch request to the server using URLSearchParams for some reason it keeps sending me an error JSON Parse error: Unexpected token: < i changes the .json to .text and it returns me this a 500 error the same exact fetch request is working fine on my react js i'm not a react native developer so i'm not sure what's the problem but after some reasearch i found out that URLSearchParams is not valid in react native so i was wondering if there's an alternative to this this is my fetch request:

```
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    if (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    if (!recaptchaToken) {
      alert("Please verify that you're a human");
      return;
    }

    
    const formData = new URLSearchParams();
    formData.append("email", email);
    formData.append("password", password);
    formData.append("passwordCheck", passwordCheck);
    formData.append("recaptcha", recaptchaToken);
    formData.append("profile", "Unfinished");


    fetch("/register", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
      body: formData,
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('data', data)
        if (data !== "Email already in use") {
          console.log("success");
        } else {
          if (data === "Email already in use") {
            setRegisterError("Cette adresse e-mail est déjà utilisée");
          } else {
            setError(data);
            console.log(error);
          }
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));

  };
```

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering why you have to use `URLSearchParams()` when you have `FormData()` already available at your disposal to solve your issue.

Use code like this, and I think it will work

```js
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append("email", email);
formData.append("password", password);
formData.append("passwordCheck", passwordCheck);
formData.append("recaptcha", recaptchaToken);
formData.append("profile", "Unfinished");

// Rest you can use fetch normally
```

In this example, we create a new `FormData` object and append the form data to it using the append method.

Comment: The thing is my backend is the problem when i use FormData i get errors and in my postion i can't touch the backend so ...

Comment: @OnsJannet, You can normally send your data in Object format if you want like a normal payload `{email: email, password: pass...}`, and simply pass it to the body. How about that?